# jQuery ajaxLoad event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen this code around:

```
$(document).on("ready ajaxLoad",function() {...});
```

in the full list of jQuery events available [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) I can not find any description about the *ajaxLoad* event.

What is this event about?

Comment: Maybe a custom event? See [jQuery Custom Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its jQuery [custom events](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```